# Problems with HAVING query

Tags: mysql, sql, exists, forall

I am following an online course on databases. However, I don't know how to proceed with this question. Can anyone help? This is my code:

```
SELECT distinct name
FROM Persons P, Knows K
WHERE K.personA_id = P.id AND K.personB_id = P.id
GROUP BY name
HAVING SUM(K.id) = 2
```

[image]

Comment: You cannot have a group by nor a having clause without an aggregate function in select list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT distinct p.name
FROM Knows K
LEFT JOIN Persons P,
ON K.personA_id = P.id 
WHERE K.personB_id 
  IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM Persons
    WHERE age>60
  )
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(K.personB_id) = 2
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT P.name
FROM Persons P
WHERE  (  SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM Knows K JOIN Persons P2 ON K.personB_id = P2.id
          WHERE K.personA_id = P.id
          AND P2.age >= 60
      ) = 2
```

but if you want to know how use the having

```
SELECT P.name
FROM Persons P JOIN Knows K ON K.personA_id = P.id 
JOIN Persons P2 ON P2.id = K.personB_id
WHERE P2.age >= 60
GROUP BY P.id
HAVING COUNT(*)=2
```

Pay attention, this query will work ONLY with MySql

Answer (score 1):

Person A and Person B will always be different in the Knows table, right?  If so, then you should not be joining on both conditions.

I suggest that you remove "AND K.personB_id = P.id"

Comment: Thank you very much, but it still doesn't return a query. I think it is because of the last two lines of my code but I am not sure. Do you know?